# A React component is getting rendered but not showing on the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A react component is not showing up on the webpage even though it is getting rendered.

I have attached the code and screenshot of the components below.

This is the code inside "App.jsx" file.

```
    function createCard(prop){
    return (<Card key={prop.id} name={prop.name} emoji={prop.emoji} desc={prop.meaning} 
    />);
    }

    function App(){
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>
    <span>emojipedia</span>
    </h1>
    {emojipedia.map(createCard)}
    </div>
    );  
    }
```

This is the code inside "Card.jsx" file.

```
    <div>
    <dl className="dictionary">
    <div className="term">
    <dt>
    <Name name="props.name" />
    <Emoji emoji="props.emoji"/>
    </dt>
    <Description desc="props.desc" />
    </div>
    </dl>
    </div>
```

In the code above, **<Description desc="props.desc />** is getting rendered but not showing up on the webpage.

Please refer to the below images:
[image: "Description" has the problem here.]

[image: The output is showing in the devTools]

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the props. Change it from desp to desc then it should work.